# Move the index finger up and down in Salah

Tags: salat, sunni, sunnah

I have seen some people move their index finger up and down constantly in Salah while sitting down.

I have also seen some people only move index finger up when saying:

> ash hadu al-La ilaha il-Lal lahu wa ash hadu anna Muhammadan abduhu wa rasuluhu.

and then move the finger down.

So which is most authentic according to hadith and sunnah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You raise the index finger in the Tashahud, but one moves it during Dua', and not constantly, as it has been narrated that the Prophet (Peace and blessings be upon him) used to raise his index finger making dua' with it:

> ثُمَّ رَفَعَ أُصْبُعَهُ فَرَأَيْتُهُ يُحَرِّكُهَا يَدْعُو بِهَا
>
> then he raised his finger and I saw him moving it, supplicating with
>   it.

[سنن النسائي (Annasa'i)](http://sunnah.com/nasai/13/90)

And this is what Ibn Uthaymeen went to, see [this (Arabic)](http://ar.islamway.net/fatwa/9151).

Comment: I've seen people move their finger up and down (constantly) during tashahud.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back that shouldn't be, the rule is not to moce it up and down as if it is being played with during salat, but a simple moving, for instance not to the far right or left, and not all the up and down.